# Numerical Integration of a high dimensional function

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, monte-carlo, quadrature

My problem is the following, I have a function, with an input vector of $\mathbb{R^{3072}}$, which outputs {$\mathbb{ x \in R : 0 \leq x \leq 1}$}. I want to find the integral of the function over the box $\mathbb{[0, 255]^{3072}}$.
I know about the function, that in most case it outputs $\mathbb{0}$ or a value close to $\mathbb{0}$ and I know some vectors for which it outputs a value close to $\mathbb{1}$. I so far tried to use crude Monte Carlo Integration in order to approximate the integral, however the results are not very good, due to the very low probability of getting a random point that results in an output close to $\mathbb{1}$. I therefore wanted to ask if someone has an idea how to tackle my problem in order to find a better approximation of the integral of my function, given the available information about the function.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I will edit the question in order to clarify. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Is it practical for you to integrate over a set of *disjoint* subregions each containing at least one of the known points where your integrand is near $1$?

Comment: I think that could work in terms of what I am trying to achieve with this. So yes it is practical

Comment: This is hopeless unless 1) your function has some special properties and 2) you know or find out about those special properties. Dimension reduction is maybe a good place to start. Nothing currently comprehensible to mankind truly depends on 3072 dimensional inputs. It seems you only have access to point evaluations. How many could you practically calculate? Do you have further knowledge beyond that many points are zero and some close to one?

Comment: Could you give examples of what some of that special properties could be ? To give you an overview I know approximately 10000 Points at which the function is close to 1 and 50000 at which it is close to 0. In terms of point evaluations, I am currently performing Monte Carlo with 210000 randomly generated Points. In terms of further knowledge the function is a function approximated by a cnn more specifically a Resnet-18 architecture.

Comment: "Special properties": Anything that helps to cut down complexity. 

Examples:
 
1) Does it really depend on all input dimensions or can you drop a few (a lot). In other words does it allow low-dimensional approximations?
One way to address this is to look at the 3072 Scatter plots of function value vs. input k. Are some scatters almost constant, monotonic, in other ways special?

2) Interactions between input dimensions. Can the function be approximated well by a Generalised Additive Model, i.e. by a sum of univariate functions?